# Augmentation for sound recognition of dog barks for CNNs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, data-augmentation, audio-recognition

I am training CNNs to recognize dog barking, and for this I would like to augment the data sets I have (~30'000 10s clips with either barks, or no-barks in them).

The straight forward idea was to mix the barking audio clips with the no-barking clips (maybe some leaves rustling or whatever), such that the resulting remix is again a barking audio clip. I did this by simply adding up the two waveforms (from .wav files) in a random ratio, e.g.

```
mix_barking_clip = 0.81 * barking_clip + 0.27 * no_barking_clip
```

However, this turns out to decrease the F1-score on the test set by quite a lot. My question is: Is this mixing technique wrong, and am I producing nonsense data with this?

Comment: no this mixing is all right, especially if you can play it and hear it. However it seems the problem is in the training itself. Maybe augment the data

Comment: Did you augment both train/val/test, or just train?

Comment: Have you listened to the resulting files? Do they still make sense?

Comment: Did you consider that the two input files might have different loudness? A loud file will dominate the less loud one when mixed with a ratio. In general you should control the signal-to-noise / foreground-to-background ratio, normally specified in dB

Comment: https://github.com/justinsalamon/scaper implements the kind of mixing, while making it easy to control SNR.